# Parsing HTML from DOM

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I'm trying to parse the alt text from the following HTML code, that I got from the Xpath denoted as "FIRST_RECORD_LINK".

```html
<img data-aria-label-part="" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Dc10VX_UwAAJxPM.jpg" alt="Millenials are more likely than Baby Boomers to be living with a disability. 
Provided by the Center for Talent Innovation Disability Inclusion Report.">
```

My javascript code looks like this:

```js
var FIRST_RECORD_LINK = '//*[@id="stream-item-tweet-999772032685527042"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/img';
var FIRST_RECORD = document.evaluate(FIRST_RECORD_LINK, document, 
    null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();
console.log(FIRST_RECORD); 
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(FIRST_RECORD,"text/html");
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute("alt"));
```

What am I doing wrong? I apologize in advance for not using the code boxes, i'm visually impaired and they're not working with my screen reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have obtained the `img` in `FIRST_RECORD` by evaluating the xpath, you can read the `alt` attribute with [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```
FIRST_RECORD.getAttribute('alt');
```

See a working example (with an updated xpath so it works in stackoverflow):

```js
// The following path was modified to work in stackoverflow
var FIRST_RECORD_LINK = '//img';
var FIRST_RECORD = document.evaluate(FIRST_RECORD_LINK, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();
console.log(FIRST_RECORD);
console.log(FIRST_RECORD.getAttribute('alt'));
```

```html
<img data-aria-label-part="" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Dc10VX_UwAAJxPM.jpg" alt="Millenials are more likely than Baby Boomers to be living with a disability. 
Provided by the Center for Talent Innovation Disability Inclusion Report.">
```